# How to enable library evolution?

Tags: swift, xcode

I maintain a small library in Swift. I read the great article from Ben Cohen about [evolution for Stable ABIs](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-library-evolution-for-stable-abis/23026). To enable library evolution mode, I have to add a new command-line argument `-enable-library-evolution`.

My problem is, that even after I add `-enable-library-evolution` argument to `Arguments passed On Launch` in my scheme settings, I still have this weird warning from Xcode:

> @frozen has no effect without -enable-library-evolution. Replace '@frozen ' with ''

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable library evolution in your **target's build settings**, not on your scheme. Look for `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION`.

Comment: One more question. I still have that "@frozen has no effect" warning in console from Cocoapods, when trying to push my a new release.
@macmade any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

set the BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION build setting in the framework’s target. This setting turns on both library evolution and module stability. Be sure to use the setting in both Debug and Release builds.

Please follow below link for Library evolution:
https://swift.org/blog/library-evolution/